# AutoCompleteTextView force to show all items OR disable filtering

Tags: android, autocomplete, filtering

I manage an `AutoCompleteTextView` that should give all the towns (ville) found in my DB, according the 4 first letters I put in.

The `Async task` works well and gets the right data.

My problem is that the `DropDownList` display NOT all the items. Often only 1, 2, 3 or 4 out of the 20 returned by the DB.

So I figured out, there should be some auto filtering within the ACTV itself!
I check many topics here on SO, to update my code but I didn't succeed.... :-(

I keep getting errors without knowing exactly what the trouble is!  :-(

- [AutoCompleteTextView force to show all items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11284368/autocompletetextview-force-to-show-all-items)
- [AutoCompleteTextView - disable filtering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8512762/autocompletetextview-disable-filtering)

So here is my code:

```
class MyActivity extends Activity implements AdapterView.OnItemClickListener
{
        static class Ville 
        {
            String id;
            String name;

            @Override
            public String toString() { return this.name; }
        };

        ArrayAdapter<Ville>    villeAdapter;
        String                 villeAdapterFilter;
        VilleUpdateTask        villeAdapterUpdateTask;
        AutoCompleteTextView   villeText;
        Ville                  selectedVille;

        final TextWatcher textChecker = new TextWatcher() {

            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {}

            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {}

            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count)
            { 
                  MyActivity.this.setAdapterFilter(s.toString());
            }

        };

        public void onCreate(Bundle bundle)
        {
             super.onCreate(bundle);
             setContentView(R.layout.main);

             this.villeAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<Ville>(this,android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, new Ville[0]);
             this.villeText = (AutoCompleteTextView ) findViewById(R.id.villeSelector);
             this.villeText.setAdapter(this.villeAdapter);
             this.villeText.setThreshold(THRESHOLD_DROPDOWN); 
             this.villeText.setOnItemClickListener(this);
             this.villeText.addTextChangedListener(textChecker);
        }

        public void onDestroy() { stopVilleAdapterUpdate(); 


        public void setAdapterFilter(String filter)
        {
             if (filter == null) {
                 // clearing the adapter
                 this.villeAdapterFilter = null;
                 this.villeAdapter.clear();
                 this.villeAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                 Log.d("MyActivity","Clearing ville filter !");
             } else if (filter.length() > THRESHOLD_QUERY) {
                  if (this.villeAdapterFilter == null) {
                      Log.d("MyActivity","Ville Adapter Filter defined to:"+filter);
                      this.villeAdapterFilter = filter;
                      startVilleAdapterUpdate();
                  } else {
                      Log.d("MyActivity","Already filtered with:"+this.villeAdapterFilter);
                  }
             } else {
                  Log.d("MyActivity","Resetting filter (not enough data)");
                  this.villeAdapterFilter = null;
                 this.villeAdapter.clear();
                 this.villeAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
             }
        }

        public synchronized void onItemClick(ViewAdapter<?> ad, View v, int position, long id)
        {
             this.selectedVille = this.villeAdapter.getItemAtPosition(position);
             Log.d("MyActivity","Ville selected: "+this.selectedVille);
        }

        public synchronized void startVilleAdapterUpdate()
        {
              stopVilleAdapterUpdate();
              Log.d("MyActivity","Starting Update of Villes with "+this.villeAdapterFilter);
              this.villeAdapterUpdateTask = new VilleUpdateTask();
              this.villeAdapterUpdateTask.execute(this.villeAdapterFilter);
        }

        public synchronized void stopVilleAdapterUpdate()
        {
             if (this.villeAdapterUpdateTask != null) {
                 Log.d("MyActivity","Stopping current update of villes");
                 this.villeAdapterUpdateTask.cancel(true);
                 this.villeAdapterUpdateTask = null;
             }
        }

        public synchronized void onVilleAdapterUpdateResult(Ville[] data)
        {
             this.villeAdapterUpdateTask = null;
             if (data != null) {
                 Log.d("MyActivity","Received "+data.length+" villes from update task");
                 this.villeAdapter.clear();
                 this.villeAdapter.addAll(data);
                 this.villeAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); // mise à jour du drop down...
            }
        } 

        class VilleUpdateTask extends AsyncTask<String,Void,Ville[]>
        {
              public Ville[] doInBackground(String ... filters)
              {
                  ArrayList<Ville> values = new ArrayList<Ville>();
                  try  {
                       HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                       ....
                       ....
                       for(int i=0;i<json_array.length();i++) {
                           JSONObject json_ligne = json_array.getJSONObject(i);   
                           try {
                               Ville v = new Ville();
                               v.name = json_ligne.getString("NAME_VILLE");
                               v.id = json_ligne.getString("ID_VILLE");
                               values.add(v);
                           } catch (Exception ex) {
                               Log.w("VilleUpdateTask","Invalid value for Ville at index #"+i,ex);
                           }
                       }
                  } catch (Exception ex) {
                       Log.e("VilleUpdateTask","Failed to retrieve list of Ville !",ex);
                  }
                  return values.toArray(new Ville[values.size()]);
             }

             public void onPostExecute(Ville[] data)
             {
                 MyActivity.this.onVilleAdapterUpdateResult(data);
             }
        }

}
```

EDIT 1: yep sorry, my ACTV is a basic **TextView**, it is not a scrolling problem because on better case I can see 10 items in the list, and last the position is random

EDIT 2: could you just help me to adapt my existing code to the given solutions from the 2 URLs above?

(1) according to that solution [AutoCompleteTextView - disable filtering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8512762/autocompletetextview-disable-filtering)

I have to:

- create my class **ClassMyACArrayAdapter** which is the same as the given one, only its name changes
- change my declaration from

  ArrayAdapter    villeAdapter;

to

```
List<ClassMyACArrayAdapter> villeAdapter;
```

- but in the onCreate what should replace the initial

  this.villeAdapter = new ArrayAdapter
  (this,android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, new Ville[0]);

Comment: setThreshold(Int.MAX_VALUE)

Answer (score 7):

Just call `autoCompleteTextView.showDropDown()` Whenever you need it.....cheers :)

Comment: Thanks, really helped to break deadlock after hrs.

Answer (score 0):

Is your AutoCompleteTextView a TextView, LinearLayout o ListView? The code in your activity looks fine, so I'm guessing that the problem could be in the layout (maybe you're not using a scroll so you can only see the first values).

Also, the values that you see are always the first ones in the returned list or they're at random positions?